# Handling dependency injection for multiple EF Core Repositories with generic class constraints

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to upgrade a project from .net 4.6.2 to .net Core.  The current version uses EF6 with Autofac dependency injection.  I'm attempting to upgrade the project to use the built in .Net Core DI as well as EF Core.  I'm running into issues setting up the .NET Core dependency injection.  I am receiving errors related to the class constraint for the repositories that take in generics.

Here are my two repositories:

```
    public partial class CustomerRepository<T> : EfRepository<T> where T : CustomerBaseEntity
    {
        public CustomerRepository(CustomerDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }
    }

    public partial class OrderRepository<T> : EfRepository<T> where T : OrderBaseEntity
    {
        public OrderRepository(OrderDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }
    }
```

Here is my EFRepository class:

```
public class EfRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
        where T : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private DbSet<T> _entities;

    public EfRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    .... <additional methods not included> ....
}
```

Entities:

```
public class CustomerBaseEntity : BaseEntity
{
}

public class OrderBaseEntity : BaseEntity
{
}

public class CustomerEntity : CustomerBaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OrderEntity : OrderBaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code for the dependency injection:

```
//DBContext
services.AddDbContext<CustomerDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionStrings:CustomerDB"]));
services.AddDbContext<OrderDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionStrings:OrderDB"]));

//Repositories
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(CustomerRepository<>));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(OrderRepository<>));
```

Here is the error I'm receiving:

```
System.ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0], 'OrderEntity', on 'CustomerRepository`1[T]' violates the constraint of type 'T'.
```

Can anyone help me understand how I can inform the DI that the CustomerRepository should only inject entity types that inherit from "CustomerBaseEntity", and OrderRepository should only inject entity types that inherit from "OrderBaseEntity"?

*** Update: I've also tried the following DI code (both unsuccessful):

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<CustomerBaseEntity>), typeof(CustomerRepository<CustomerBaseEntity>));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<OrderBaseEntity>), typeof(OrderRepository<OrderBaseEntity>));

and

services.AddScoped(IRepository<CustomerBaseEntity>, CustomerRepository<CustomerBaseEntity>);
services.AddScoped(IRepository<OrderBaseEntity>, OrderRepository<OrderBaseEntity>);
```

Comment: The DI registration code looks suspect in that you are registering the IRepository<> twice.  So when you code has a constructor that has an IRepository<> parameter, how does it know which implementation to pick to inject?  I would think you'd get a runtime exception that says the dependency is ambiguous, but it looks like it's just picking the first instance you registered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Fran.  I've tried the following and this does not work either.   services.AddScoped(IRepository<CustomerBaseEntity>, CustomerRepository<CustomerBaseEntity>);

Comment: Why on earth would I have a Customer*BaseEntity* Repository rather than a CustomerEntityRepository???  Sorry, but 2001 called and wanted several excessive layers of inheritance back. Honestly, an over-dependence on inheritance is a code smell, and generic repository patterns are a code smell. Combining them is one heck of a stinker.

Comment: Yeah I used to use a generic repo, but i've moved to using the DbContext directly.  the ef enhancements with adding the in memory database for "unit" testing the code makes writing testable code easy.  So I'd listen to @StevePy and collapse your architecture.

Comment: Fran & Steve, this is an upgrade to existing code, so we wanted to avoid rewriting everything.  But in the end, it sounds like you don't know how to do this with .NET DI so maybe we'll need to continue to use Autofac.  Thanks for your replies.  As to having a "CustomerEntityRepository", we have that... it's called CustomerRepository.  The base entities are for the purposes of added new entities and identifying the context they belong to.